# How to make a NSTextView out of many, the first recipient in viewDidLoad?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextview

I used "becomeFirstResponder" on tv2, but any text inputed goes to tv1.  How do I set this to go to tv2 in this setup.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tv1 = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
    [self.view addSubview:tv1];
    tv1.string = @"dog";

    tv2 = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 100, 50)];
    [self.view addSubview:tv2];
    tv2.string = @"cat";

    [tv2 becomeFirstResponder]; //fails to make this one take in keys strokes
```

Comment: `becomeFirstResponder`: "Use the `NSWindow` `makeFirstResponder:` method, not this method, to make an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly."

Comment: I have done that as well... did not work.  The only way it works is if I create a NSButton and do [ self.view.window makeFirstResponder:  tv2 ]; in the callBack.

Comment: When do you do `makeFirstResponder`? It could be too early.

Comment: I opened a new project... and this was it, aside from adding the button and callback.  I had also tried NSNotification at the end of this method would work... nope.

Comment: Did you try `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: that did it..thx